# Анимацию перехода от Fragment в Fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin, анимация, android-fragment

У меня есть два фрагмента, и я хочу что бы во время replace одного фрагмента другим, выполнялась анимация, что-то по типу - первый фрагмент остается на месте, а второй накладывается на него справа, при нажатии на клавишу назад, второй фрагмент уезжает в права, тем самый первый фрагмент становится видимым, но негде не наше примера реализации такой анимации, а у самого не выходит

Comment: Завтра если не забуду, напишу ответ. На java правда. Но андроид студио сам переведет. Я у себя реализовал это

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую такой код

```
FragmentManager fm;
fm.beginTransaction()
     .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.to_right_in, R.anim.to_right_out, R.anim.to_left_in, R.anim.to_left_out)
     .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, _fragment)
     .addToBackStack(null)
     .commit();
```

Также необходимо добавить в res/anim 4 файла: to_right_in, to_right_out, to_left_in, to_left_out.

to_left_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    >
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%" />
</set>
```

to_left_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    >
    <translate android:toXDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

to_right_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    >
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" />
</set>
```

to_right_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    >
    <translate android:toXDelta="100%" />
</set>
```